# how to change Facebook quote plugin thumbnail, now its taking bitnami icon image

Tags: facebook

I have using the below code for sharing custom text in facebook. how to change the thumbnail which was showing in the left side of the post(custom text) ?

`<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A//www.primarycarehaiti.com/share-it"><img src="http://www.primarycarehaiti.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/fbshare_image.png" title="Facebook Share" style="position: relative;top: -2px;" alt="facebook" /></a>`

this is the share link while adding this link. please check this link to show the result.

https://www.screencast.com/t/eCyVOSJGD

Please provide suggestion's.

Thanks

Comment: but, the thumbnail is now taking from bitnami logo. how to change it. i have tested your reference links. but not change.

Comment: What have you tested? Be specific, and edit your question to show us what you have done. Also, use the Facebook debug tool to check if your implementation is correct.

Comment: Facebook debug tool is helpful and now the issue is fixed. "Time Scraped" functionality is helped.